# Insert into database using Entity Framework from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a text file formatted in C Sharp to a Microsoft SQL server. I have 2 tables Transaction and TMatch in which I want to populate the data. 4  attributes each. I have created 2 classes for each. I am aware of how to input data manually into the database through the `.Add()` and `.SaveChanges()`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Database insertions
TTransaction txn = new TTransaction();
**txn.Amount = 56;    //I want a variable used below (AMOUNT) to go into amount.
txn.TRN = "sdfgsdfg";** //(TxnNo) to go into TRN

ScotiaNYAEntities context = new ScotiaNYAEntities();
context.TTransactions.Add(txn);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Traversing the text file using a while loop.

```
{
    if (line.Contains("AMOUNT:"))  //Look where to end for Transaction Text
    {   
        // For Amount
        IsAmount=true;
        if(IsAmount)
        {
            Amount = line.Replace("AMOUNT:", String.Empty).Trim();
            Console.WriteLine("AMOUNT: ********");
            Console.WriteLine(Amount);
        }
    }..............................................
```

I am not sure how to reference a variable instead of just values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

In the for loop for reading the file line by line

```
 String TxnLOC = null;
                IsTransactionLocation= false;
                if (line.Contains("TRANSACTION LOC:"))
                {
                    IsTransactionLocation = true;
                    if (IsTransactionLocation)
                    {
                        TxnLOC = line.Replace("TRANSACTION LOC:", String.Empty).Trim();
                        Console.WriteLine("The Transaction Location: ********");
                        Console.WriteLine(TxnLOC);

                    //Database insertion fot TTransaction Table
                    TTransaction txn = new TTransaction();

                    txn.TRN = txnNo;
                    txn.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Amount);
                    txn.TransactionLocation = TxnLOC;

                    context.TTransaction.Add(txn); //Adding to the database
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    IsTxnSection = false;//For 1 to many relationship


                }


               }
```

Answer (score 0):

leap of faith but you could have something like this

```
using (ScotiaNYAEntities context = new ScotiaNYAEntities())  
{
  foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(pathToFile))
  {
    if (line.Contains("AMOUNT:"))
    {
      if (IsAmount)
      {
        string amount = line.Replace("AMOUNT:", string.Empty).Trim();

        TTransaction txn = new TTransaction();

        txn.Amount = amount;
        txn.TRN = "sdfgsdfg";

        context.TTransactions.Add(txn);
      }
    }
  }

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer, but I am not able to fit in similar attributes like amount which is TRN (having a different IF condition. If I add them within the loop (Some are stringbuilders) which adds one line instead of the whole string for a single ID.

Comment: its not really clear what you're trying to do without more examples

Comment: I finally got it to make it work using your example, thanks man!